# Can a simcard's public IP be accessed?

Tags: attacks, ip, iot, simcard

I am in a discussion with someone about IoT devices.
We use private IPs for simcards, but the other organisation is using public IPs.

I think it is possible for a hacker to access these public IPs to attack the IoT device, but is this true? Or what is the main security reason for not using a public IP?

Comment: Whether or not it is fixed does not matter in terms of "sniffing". How does "sniffing" result in "attacking"?

Comment: Your security should not be based on private IP's. It should be based on *actual* protection such as firewalls.

Comment: Schroeder: Fixed has nothing to do with it, it's about private or public. About the sniffing: when someone can find a device "sniffing" the area, they can try to access it.

Vidarlo: In IoT/M2M a lot of devices are sensors with SIMmodules. Yes, there are firewalls while the data is traveling from device > cell tower > datacenter > datacenter client. But not always on the device itself.

All: To make my question more specific: Why should I, based on security, choose private IP over Public IP or vice versa.

Comment: "Sniffing" is not at all what you are concerned about, either, then. You want to know what the risks are of having a device directly accessible to the Internet. And the risks there are the same for any device and not specific to IoT. And then the concern is not about public/private IP, but about having a firewall in between, as vidario says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile network subscribers' access to the Internet (whether IoT or not) is almost always behind something called Carrier Grade NAT (or CG-NAT, CGN). This means the IPv4 address of the subscriber (or device) is private, and never directly exposed to the Internet. A while back we ran out of IPv4 public addresses, so on most mobile networks you can't get an assigned & publicly exposed IPv4 address even if you wanted.

Law enforcement has a huge problem with that (for obvious reasons) and has lobbied for years to have service providers stop using CG-NAT. However, service providers aren't in a real rush to adopt IPv6, and are maximizing their current investment (implementing IPv6 across a carrier's network isn't exactly easy or cheap). One of the carriers' excuses has been security - that removing CG-NAT will expose customers to cybersecurity threats.

Exposing devices directly to the Internet greatly increases the likelihood of them being attacked. IoT devices typically do not have an easy way to receive patches, their support cycle is short (vendors focus on releasing the next product, obsoleting the previous), and are rarely designed with security in mind (cost, simplicity, and functionality being the main design drivers).

Threat actors are actively looking to exploit these weaknesses (check out [Mirai](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2020/05/20/cybersecurity-practices-implement-secured-devices/) and [Mozi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2021/08/19/how-to-proactively-defend-against-mozi-iot-botnet/) IoT botnets), and running IoT devices with public IPv4 addresses is surely going to come with a lot of risks.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a lot!